# No initial sign up captcha (prone to exploits)

Tags: support, registration

I have noticed that when signing up using the normal procedure, the user is not required to fill in a captcha. At first I thought that it would be a problem, but SO is made smart enough to track the IP address and put captcha the second time you try to register. Nevertheless, I still think this might cause some problems.

Let's say we have the following scenario where a malicious user creates a script to do the following:

1. Generate N random emails
2. Use multiple proxies (or tor-like system) to change the origin of accessing the website
3. Register a user with random free name (generated using a dictionary most likely)
4. Authenticate the user using the sent emails from the system.

I think this might cause some problems for the admins of the website, so don't you think showing a captcha even the first time a user tries to sign up would correct this behavior?

Comment: If it becomes an actual problem, it's generally easy enough to add the functionality in.  If it's not actually a problem due to the current barriers that are in place, then it would seem that this isn't needed.

Comment: Just wondering what problems you had in mind?

Comment: I had in mind taking many of the good usernames not making spam bots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step three is not needed; the system generates a username for you anyway, based on the numeric user id. Note that [user *names* are not unique](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25404/why-does-stack-overflow-allow-duplicate-display-names), more than one person can call themselves "Jon Skeet" or "Martijn Pieters" (although outright *impersonation* is not allowed).

Spammers *already* sign up through Tor and post spam, but the SE automated spam detection has gotten to be rather good at catching these. The few posts that still get through are handled by the community; the average lifespan of a spam post on Stack Overflow is measured in minutes, tops.

In other words: there is no problem, really. Spammers already are getting caught pretty early and often. How much spam have you seen on Stack Overflow lately?

So why inconvenience *actual, proper users with an extra roadblock like a captcha*?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say Martijn, but the problem here is not spam, but people that decide to take all the "nice" usernames using a system like that. They won't be unregistered although they do not post anything. So next time you try to register your brother (let's say Joop Pieters) it might have been taken by the script.

Comment: @zigi: Usernames are not 'unique'. Only user *ids* are, those numbers in the user account URL. You can call yourself "Martijn Pieters" **right now**. Impersonating other people is frowned upon though, but duplicate names *are allowed*.

Comment: Ok excuse me then, I did not know that actually the user has an id which is different than his username. I thought it was since when you refer to someone with an *@* symbol it refers to everyone with that name that is related to the post/chat.

Comment: @zigi: Usernames are not a scarce commodity. And all spammers want to do spew their dubious wares and malware-ridden links.

Comment: @zigi: there are [3339 accounts named "Alex" on Stack Overflow](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/147990/100-most-common-usernames).